# Why am I wielding shoes instead of a bow?

Tags: diablo-iii

I haven't played Diablo in about 2 days, but when I switched it on just now, I noticed that my demon hunter is holding a pair of shoes instead of a bow in her hand! What should i do? I added a picture here as well

[image: shoes instead of bow]

Comment: You should kill things with shoes.

Comment: Where can i get a pair like that? Are they gucci?!?

Comment: Erm, what does your inventory say they are called or classified as? Might be a glitch... or a weird easter egg, but in leaning with glitch based on how it looks

Comment: My bow is called Odyssey's End, its an ancient legendary bow.. i have 3 sockets in it. I think that its a glitch too

Comment: AFAIK things can have three sockets, I remember having an armor piece of one of my characters with three sockets. As for the shoes... they're a fine pair, almost look like luxury Chucks, but likely a glitch.

Comment: This is awesome, I want those shoes

Comment: Using any modded gear?

Comment: @Kaizerwolf While chest pieces can normally roll with 1-3 sockets, I believe the only weapon in the game to ever be able to roll with more than one socket was the pre-RoS Manticore, which could have 2.

Comment: Is this on PC or console?

Answer (score 7):

> My bow is called Odyssey's End, its an ancient legendary bow.. i have 3 sockets in it. I think that its a glitch too – Victoria

*Comment from OP*

While I do not have proof I belive you are using a hacked item, this may or may not be intentional, your comment supports this as weapons may only have 0-1 sockets.

You have 2 paths to take at this point continue playing with the item (and risk being banned) or salvage/discard the item(s) and continue to play as normal.

I will mention that a friend of mine did use hacked items on D3 for the PS4 for several months without any issues (after which he said he got bored of the game and stopped playing, maybe because of a ban or not, it is unclear)

As to why the skin is that of boots, I do not know, hacked items can be anything so it may have been made as a bit of a joke

Comment: While Blizzard do have unspecified plans to fix the widespread hacked items on the console versions, I am not aware of anyone ever being banned for it so far.

Comment: There are soon to be Seasons in the console version of the game which will save the character information on a blizz controlled server. It's probably separated enough to where if you have this item on your normal character and not on your season character you wont have problems, but once seasons come to console, be very wary of using hacked items.